# Villain Character Ideas

Tags: characters, character-development, fantasy

I'm making a story. I have a female superhero character.

> She live in normal Earth, without any combination of legends. She was a normal human in the past, but an experiment caused her to have superpowers. She can live both in water and land. But, her superpowers are optimal when used in water. Her superpowers are almost same like Aquaman's.

I need ideas for a villain for her to fight. I think, it's best if you come up with **underwater villain** ideas. I have searched for **Aquaman** as my reference. But, Aquaman is different with my superhero character, he is a human-Atlantean Hybrid, while mine is pure human. You can use another reference for your ideas, rather than Aquaman.

Please give detail villain ideas, including his/her **origin, name, appearance, powers, and motives**. Thanks

Comment: I love this question. It's formatted nicely, easy to read, and generally a good question. However, questions based on the theme of *what to write* are **off topic** on this site.

Comment: Wouldn't it also be somewhat a shame if one of the most important characters in your story wasn't made by you? I'm sure people feel different about this kind of thing, but I personally like "complete ownership" of the characters/content of my story. Yes i know "we're all inspired by everything", but this, to me, takes the inspiration out as well.. I just think you care more about your story, the more ownership you have of it. Maybe I'm different here..

Comment: @DanielCann For that **off topic** thing, I saw some questions posted in this site about looking for ideas too, and those questions aren't put as off topic, that's why I asked about ideas too. But anyway, thanks for your compliment.

Comment: @storbror Thanks for your advice. I had thought about some ideas before, and then I thought those ideas weren't very good, so I need help to have better ideas

Comment: Sure. Also, when answers were submitted here, I realized they were quite broad, or could be interpreted and used in many ways. This of course makes it less of a "use this character" situation.

Comment: But if you want to ask  other questions, I'll answer all of them, because these are the best kinds of questions that clearly have effort put into them @GraceMichelle

Comment: @GraceMichelle Can you please provide examples? There are sometimes subtle differences. (Feel free to open up a thread on meta if you like.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Founder of an underwater mining corporation.** They extract oil in a way similar to oil platforms, but they do it underwater and therefore don't care about safety requirements. Maybe they have giant submarines and if an accident happens, the submarine simply travels to a different location.

Some combination of oil company, drug cartel (illegal, hidden, and global) and casino ship (doesn't belong to any country).

Your protagonist also lives in the water and the oil spills created by the corporation of the villain endanger her habitat.

Possible start of the story: The corporation causes an oil spill comparable to [Deepwater Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepwater_Horizon_oil_spill) and it somehow touches the protagonist. But contrary to BP, the government can't punish it and that's why a person with superpowers is required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like your idea (and the details), it reminds the reader about nature. I've accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

- The evil twin

  While your hero discovers she has an evil twin with similar powers and an economic knack who will take revenge on the humans for all they have done to the see.
- BBC - Big Bad Company.

  Underwater is full of resources and harvesting them threatens the
  home of your superhero mermaid. The head of the company on the other
  hand also is very generous to the public, so she just cannot go there
  and kill him.
- Ancient alien life. Ie Ie Cthulhu ftahgn!

Comment: I like the addition here, that the head of the company is very generous to the public. Usually, charismatic or relatable "enemies" make for much more interesting stories and struggles. See Christoph Waltz in "Inglorious Basterds". He's brilliant because we instinctively hate him for being on the nazies' side, but his behaviour and relation to "the good guys" makes us question how we actually feel about him. Also, avoiding "all evil" vs "all good" makes for a more realistic feel, though I suppose superhero stories don't need to be as realistic as for instance sci-fi.

Comment: @storbror Thanks for your comment. I am also not a fan of all-evil vs all-good because it lacks possibilities for character and story development

Comment: Exactly! Also, if we can "simply" solve the issue by killing "the villain", the struggle is less (potentially) interesting and more (potentially) frustrating. Frustration can be important, but frustration alone probably isn't optimal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like the second one, it makes the story unpredictable. I really want to upvote your answer, but sorry, my rep is still not enough to do that

Comment: @GraceMichelle No problem. You can always upvote at a later time. But I'm not here for the reputation ;) Have fun writing your story

Comment: You are the first user who says that you aren't here for rep. I appreciate that ;) Thanks again